# AC3 TrueHD/7.1 Atmos Has No Sound

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

My previous 7.1 question went unsolved, so I tried to map the audio streams this time. I am now getting the 5.1 at least, but the AC3 TrueHD/7.1 Atmos channel is empty. I mapped the video and two audio channels I wanted and chose to copy each of them, then I brought up the results of the output. See below:

```
C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffmpeg -i 01.m2ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy out.m2ts
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mpegts @ 00000164f8d98dc0] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000164f8d98dc0] start time for stream 4 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000164f8d98dc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 00000164f8d98dc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from '01.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:06:30.27, start: 11.650667, bitrate: 35679 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
    Stream #0:4[0x1201]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
Output #0, mpegts, to 'out.m2ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9357 fps=2147 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1642506kB time=00:06:30.26 bitrate=34477.7kbits/s speed=89.6x
video:1428645kB audio:138442kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.812665%

C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffmpeg -i out.m2ts
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mp3float @ 000002d237c2acc0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 81 times
[mpegts @ 000002d237c287c0] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mpegts @ 000002d237c287c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp3 (mp3float) ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:06:30.27, start: 1.441711, bitrate: 34477 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp3 ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 0 channels, fltp
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified

C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>
```

Why is 0:1 showing 0 channels?

New Output Using -Strict -2:

```
C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffmpeg -i output.m2ts
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'output.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:00:55.75, start: 1.433311, bitrate: 20154 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: truehd ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
```

Answer (score -1):

> ffmpeg -i 01.m2ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy out.m2ts

try

```
ffmpeg -i 01.m2ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c copy -c copy -strict -2  -c copy -strict -2 output.m2ts
```

please post the info of the new file

ffmpeg -i output.m2ts

*Considered that 32bits audios, dont work in html5 navigators, you will to changed from 24bits to 16bits, enjoy your work, regards.

Comment: Only one `-c copy` is needed. `-strict -2` is doing nothing and is being ignored as there are no experimental components involved here to require compliance. Regardless, your answer will result in the same problem as in the question.

Comment: I have posted above the results of using -strict -2. It did something and it looks like the audio is there (doesn't say mp3 anymore), but when played, 0:1 is still silent. Also, 0:1 and 0:2 used to be seen as 1 track by players. If the player could handle the TrueHD, it would play that, if not, it'd play 0:2. Now they are being seen as separate.

Comment: @Huston sorry, i dont see this new info
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: truehd ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side),

The Stream 0:1 is in 32 bits, unfortunately, you will have to lower the bit rate to 16 of that track, because if not it will never work, unless you have the specific codecs of trueHD, see the new answer